# $SERVER variable and the double localhost

Tags: php, url-routing

I've built a function that basically links an excerpt to its relative post. In order to do that I have figured that the variable `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` could come in handy in building the path.

I don't know if this is due to the fact I am testing the page on a local environment, but on my local machine the path I have is like `http://localhost/webdir/localhost/index.php?p=3` `localhost` is repeated twice. What could possibly cause this?

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but it should be `$_SERVER`

Comment: How do you build that path?

Comment: There is probably a directory called localhost in webdir, have you looked to see?

Comment: @galymzhan: it's not, I got a typo here! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
$link='http://'.$SERVER_['SERVER_NAME'];
```

And if you don't want any GET type of value use this

```
$l1=explode('?',$SERVER_['SERVER_NAME']);
$link='http://'.$l1[0];
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Yes, thank you!! I got rid of the second `localhost` thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try even this
Edit works great for almost all type of URL..

```
<?php
$l1=explode('?',$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);

$link='http://'.$l1[0];
echo $link;
echo '<h2><center>Add users</center></h2>';
$pageURL = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$pageURL1 = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80' ? $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pageURL=$pageURL.$pageURL1;
//$pageURLt=explode('?',$pageURL);//Uncomment this and next line if you don't want get variable
//$pageURL=$pageURL.$pageURLt[0];
echo $pageURL;

?>
```